# org-mode with setting up a capture location in emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I put this in my .emacs file:

```lisp
(setq org-default-notes-file (concat org-directory "/notes.org"))
(define-key global-map "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
```

But when I open emacs, this occurs:

> Symbol's value as variable is void:org-directory

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to set `org-directory` with something like `(setq org-directory "folder")` otherwise it will be undefined and produce an error

Comment: @Niklaus Please consider to upvote and accept the answer if it answered your question, see [faq#howtoask].